# Rails get created nested record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm creating a single associated record in a has_many association via nested_attributes like so

```
#Parent Model
has_many :child_models

#Parent Controller
def create
  parentModel.update_attributes(parent_model_params_with_nested_child_attributes)
end
```

Pretty basic, but after the update created a new ChildModel I want to add some other data to it, so I need to get a reference to the ChildModel that was just created.

```
parentModel.childModels.order("id DESC").first
```

since that SHOULD contain the most recently created association, but I'm wondering if A) that's true and B) there isn't a better way.

Comment: You're violating basic assumed Rails naming conventions for models. If the model code file is `ChildModel.rb`, then the association name should be `child_model` (or pluralized, `child_models`, *e.g.*, `has_many :child_models`). Otherwise, you're going to run into a lot of issues getting it to work and maintaining it properly.

Comment: I know, this is just air code. I'll edit the questions though.

Comment: Have you considered using, `parent.child_models.order("created_at").last`?